# Parsing Nested Json with Jackson Annotation in Scala

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I am parsing a JSON file using the Jackson Annotation and specifically the JsonProperty in Scala.

The JSON file comes in like:

```
{
   "expand":"schema",
   "maxResults":50,
   "total":542,
   "issues":[
      {
         "expand":"operation,transit",
         "id":"23121",
         "fields":{
            "customfield":null,
            "priority":{
               "name":"This",
               "id":"35"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I have created a case class that does a good job in parsing the top level attributes but I have a problem when having to parse the nested values (e.g. ***issues.fields.priority.id***)

The snippet of the code is:

```
case class GetResults(

@JsonProperty("expand") expand:String

@JsonProperty("maxResults") maxResults: Int

@JsonProperty("total") total: Int

@JsonProperty("issues") issues: JValue
```

This way I am getting all of the values that are included in issues as a JValue, but I can not parse them by calling something like ***issues.fields.priority.id***

I tried:
`@JsonProperty("issues") issues.fields.priority.id: Int`, but it doesnt work.

Any clue on how can I do it by using this specific case class and the jackson annotation?

Comment: Hi iolkos, you JSON has a weird look. Could you fix it please?

Comment: For your question, don't you want to define a case class for the fields property?

Comment: But how can I define a case class inside the "issues" property ?@AlbanDericbourg. What do you mean about the JSON format?

Comment: The JSON is not properly formatted and is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

You could define nested case classes:

```
case class GetResults (
  expand: String, 
  maxResults: Int,
  total: Int,
  issues: Seq[Issues]
)

case class Issues (
  expand: String,
  id: Int,
  fields: Fields
)

case class Fields (
  customfield: ???,
  priority: Priority
)

case class Priority (
  name: String,
  id: Int
)
```

I removed the `@JsonProperty` annotations to ease reading but you actually have to add them just like you did.

Comment: The issue is that inside Fields, there are around 150 attributes that need to be defined manually, and many of them (e.g. "Priority" need further definitions).
I was wondering if there was an easier and more automatic way that would help me read the specific values I want after parsing.

Comment: Mapping they as a Map?